# Position and Velocity vector

Tags: calculus

How do you find the velocity vector if the position vector is given by  $\langle \sec t, \tan t \rangle$ ? I am familiar with the method of deriving position to get velocity but this is given as a vector itself not an equation.

Comment: We need more information. Do you have a parameterization of the position at least?

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate position with respect to time component-wise to get the velocity vector, which is what you asked for:
$$\mathbf{\vec{v}} = \left\langle \frac{d}{dt}(\sec t) , \frac{d}{dt}(\tan t) \right\rangle$$

It’s just like if you wrote position in terms of constant unit vectors and then differentiated that:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{\vec r} &= \mathbf{\hat i} \sec(t) + \mathbf{\hat j} \tan(t) \\
\frac{d\mathbf{\vec r}}{dt} &= \frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf{\hat i} \sec t) + \frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf{\hat j} \tan t) \\
\mathbf{\vec v} &= \mathbf{\hat i}\frac{d}{dt}( \sec t) + \mathbf{\hat j}\frac{d}{dt}( \tan t)
\end{align}$$